# Normal random variables, joint distribution

Tags: probability-theory

If I have two normally distributed random variables, is their joint distribution always elliptical, i.e. fully characterized by a mean vector and variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: No: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: For a great answer `No` to this question, see [this one on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/6633).

Comment: --------Thank you!             .